# Select/Edit/Enter blocks(vertically) of text in MS Word / Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-word

I would like to **`select/enter/edit`** blocks of text (vertically) in `MS Word` or `MS EXCEL`. 
The key shortcut `SHIFT+ALT` can achieve the same in  SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 and up. Is there anything equivalent in `MS Word` or`MS EXCEL`.

Answer (score 1):

SHIFT+ALT does work for vertically selecting text in MS WORD.

Comment: Just holding the ALT will work for vertical selection. but it won't let edit or enter text.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the front end in SSMS to add/edit data anyway.

Comment: That is correct. You can cut,copy, and delete the text but it won't let you edit it. I just tested it.